# IE/Firefox CSS confusion: Why does my table have inside borders on Firefox, but not IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, border, css-tables

I'm having a problem with CSS not displaying correctly between IE and Firefox... The big problem is that we have a ridiculous number of CSS files (and this isn't something that is currently scoped to fix), and I can't seem to find what style is being applied.

Any way, here's what I'm looking at:  On the shopping cart page for our site, we have a table (yes, I know) where each row is an item in the cart.  On IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari, this table renders fine - everything looks good, borders are all hidden, it looks great.  On Firefox, however, while the outer border on the table remains hidden, lines separating columns/rows *inside* the table are displayed.

I don't have direct links to show the problem, but if you go to

https://store.petango.com/Roc-P6986.aspx

and click the "Add to cart" button, it brings you to the cart page (where you can see the lines showing in FFox, but not in IE).

For what it's worth, this is a third party E-Commerce package that we purchased, and on top of that we hired out our web design to a DIFFERENT third party web developer.  Hence the jumbled mass of CSS files/confusion.  Trying to look at the CSS for specific TD elements (in Firebug) is basically impossible to read it's so long, but I can't see anything obvious in there either.

I would be *thrilled* if this is just something stupid I'm missing, and there's a well known mistake that has been made in our CSS that lets it render fine in every browser but Firefox - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without looking at your code, do you have margin on the table/cells? Or cellspacing?

Comment: I'm afraid the well-known mistake here is in using a set of CSS rules so complex that you can't debug them with Firebug...

Comment: Thanks Shog - but I think I was pretty clear in my distaste at the complication of the project as it stands. :P

Christopher - there are divs within each cell, and the divs have margins, but there are no margins on the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of poking around in Firebug reveals that removing the `border-collapse:collapse` style from the `ctl00_wpm_Basket_ctl04_BasketGrid` table removes the borders. I'm not even going to try to explain this - the style should be completely unnecessary, as like many of the other applicable styles it's set and reset multiple times at multiple levels... I suspect you're encountering some subtle difference between how styles are applied in Gecko and other browsers; it's probably a bug, but I would encourage you to slim down the test case if you decide to report it...

> this isn't something that is currently scoped to fix

It probably should be... Otherwise, you'd better get comfortable using Firebug.

Comment: Actually, a bit of further digging in Firebug (trying to find some margins or cellspacing relevant to Christopher Altman's comment above) I noticed that border-collapse setting as well, and recalled reading something about this in other net searches (before giving up and posting here).  Now, the key is finding out WHICH CSS file and which entry this is inherited from.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan: It's defined on the table itself - as an inline style! Since I don't know how your HTML is generated, I can't say whether it's hard-coded into the markup or generated by some sort of server-side processing, but it's definitely not coming from a static CSS file.

Comment: Oh ugh - no wonder I can't find it... it's an ASP gridview control, and apparently (Go Microsoft!) there's a bug that the table generated by ASP gridviews ALWAYS outputs this style.  Thanks, I'll go and find the workaround for *that* now.  LE SIGH.

Comment: And the workaround to that is, of course, setting the "Gridlines" attribute to "None".

Answer (score 0):

"We fully recognize that IE is behind the game today in CSS support."

[ieblog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151125042213/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/07/29/445242.aspx)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this is relevant to my problem?

Comment: That article is 5 years old, plus the questions says "...lets it render fine in every browser but Firefox."  I don't think this is an IE6 issue.  ;)

Comment: Completely irrelevant and not even an answer; I should downvote.  But +1 for IE bashing.  :)